# validar si un registro existe antes de insertar en PHP Nativo

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me Podrian ayudar solucionando
Como validar un usuario registrado antes de registrarlo

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega código en vez de imagen para poder tratar de ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

aqui te pongo un ejemplo simple, usando PDO:

```
 public static function login ($user, $pass) {
    $query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `user`=:user and `pass`=:pass");
    $query->execute(["user" => $user,"pass"  => $pass]);
    return $result = ($query->rowCount() == 1) ?  $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC):0;
}

if ($sql !=0) {
            header("Location:login.php")
        }else {
            "Error al iniciar sesion";
        }
```

Comment: Deberías explicar tu código amigo

Answer (score 0):

esto te puede ayudar. Básicamente primero hacemos una consulta a la base de datos y dependiendo del retorno de respuesta evaluamos si se inserta el registro o no.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $host='valor'; #tu servidor o localhost
    $usuario='valor'; #usuario de la base de datos
    $password='valor'; #contraseña de la base de datos
    $bd='valor'; #base de datos

    #Petición de conexión
    $conexion = new mysqli($host,$usuario,$password,$bd) or die('could not connect to database');

    #variable con el registro que se va a insertar
    $registro_id = $_POST['registro_id']; 

    #Se hace una consulta a la tabla registros de base de datos, se usa COUNT para saber cuántos registros tiene.
    $queryRegistro = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(registro_id) AS cantidad FROM registros WHERE registro_id =".$registro_id."");
    $row = $queryRegistro->fetch_assoc();

    #Si la cantidad es mayor a 0 significa que ya hay un registro, por lo contrario, se inserta a la base de datos.
    if($row['cantidad'] >0) {
        echo '¡Vaya!, esto ya tiene un registro ';
    }else{
        $queryOrder = "INSERT INTO `registros`(`registro_id`)
        VALUES ('$registro_id')";

        if (mysqli_query($conexion, $queryOrder)) {
            echo $nombre. ', registro creado con éxito ';
        } else {
            echo 'Error inesperado.';
        }
    }
    $conexion->close();
?>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Amigo la consulta del select no me esta devolvimendo nada :C

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con el nuevo código, de lo contrario, no sé en qué está fallando. Seguramente estás haciendo algo mal, el código que te puse previamente lo probe, dime, a qué te refieres exactamente que no te devuelve nada.